# Standalone async web API on Mono

Tags: mono, servicestack, async-await, asp.net-web-api

Has anybody had success (production code) with hosting a standalone async web API (asp.net web API) based service on Mono? By standalone I mean hosting the API in a console app outside of asp.net.

I am looking for a simple way to create a REST API and I would really really like to make my stack async (C#5 style) from the top HTTP layer to the bottom data access layer, now that C#5 has such good support for it.

Normally I would go with ServiceStack and host this as a daemon on Linux, but because ServiceStack does not support the new C#5 async stuff in their services (as far as I know), I am considering using a self-hosted async web API on Mono.

I know that there is some async branch on the way in ServiceStack, but it is not ready, and I know that there are some asynconeway things in ServiceStack, but I don't think this is using the new task based async stuff in C#5.

So my question is whether it is possible and stable enough to make a REST service using a self-hosted async web API on mono, or if it is better just to use synchronous ServiceStack when doing standalone hosting on Mono?

Answer (score 9):

Better use [async NancyFx](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Async-Beta). Web API is not well supported on Mono (yet). With Nancy, you would do like:

```
public Module()
{
    Get["/greet/{name}"] = async x => {
        await Task.Delay(5000);
        return string.Concat("Hello ", x.name);
    };
}
```

Comment: ok thanks. It seems though as id NancyFc async still is beta. Is Web Api useless on mono ?

Comment: Support for Web API & MVC 4 in mono 3.0 is not complete as far as I can tell. You may get occasional exceptions. NancyFx async is still beta too so no solution is perfect for Mono at the moment.

Comment: The Nancy Async support is technically beta, but it's in production in quite a few places and the only bug we've had so far is about unwrapping aggregate exceptions, so it's solid :)

Answer (score 4):

Not exactly standalone application, but check this tutorial on [Running ASP.NET Web API services under Linux and OS X](http://www.piotrwalat.net/running-asp-net-web-api-services-under-linux-and-os-x/) It shows how to run ASP.net Web API from UNIX based OSs.